# Is this the right way of using Object.defineProperty()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function addjsUserData(xAxiz, xTextArea, yAxiz, yTextArea) {

        var xlines = xTextArea.split('\n');
        var ylines = yTextArea.split('\n');
        jsdata = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < xlines.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < ylines.length; j++) {
                var jsUserObject = new Object();
                Object.defineProperty(jsUserObject, xAxiz, {
                    value: xlines[i],
                    writable: true
                });
                Object.defineProperty(jsUserObject, yAxiz, {
                    value: parseFloat(ylines[i]),
                    writable: true
                });


            }
            jsdata.push(jsUserObject)

        }
        console.log(jsdata);
        console.log(Object.keys(jsdata)[0]);
```

I have two loops. Then I create an object inside the loop. I want the user to set the x-axis and y-axis for my barchart. The values for the x-axis and y-axis is also set in a textarea. I want the user to define the properties of my jsuserdata array and also the values. However, I can't seem to access it after the user has defined the property. May I know what is the correct way to approach this? BTW, Object.keys(jsdata)[0] is showing just 0 instead of xAxiz variable .

Comment: `Object.keys(jsdata)[0]` returns `0`, because you're accessing the keys of an array, of which the first will always be `0`. Try `Object.keys(jsdata[0])` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `Object.defineProperty`. You can set dynamic property names using the `[]` notation:

```
 var propName = "hello";
 var obj = {};
 obj[propName] = "world";
 console.log(obj.hello); // Logs "world"
```

In an example that (I imagine) is similar to what you're trying to do:

```js
function createDataPoints(xAxisLabel, xAxisValues, yAxisLabel, yAxisValues) {
  var dataPoints = [];
  var nrOfValidPoints = Math.min(xAxisValues.length, yAxisValues.length);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nrOfValidPoints; i += 1) {
    var newDataPoint = {};
    newDataPoint[xAxisLabel] = xAxisValues[i];
    newDataPoint[yAxisLabel] = yAxisValues[i];
    
    dataPoints.push(newDataPoint);
  }
  
  return dataPoints;
};

function onImportClick() {
  var xAxisLabel = document.getElementById("xAxisLabel").value;
  var yAxisLabel = document.getElementById("yAxisLabel").value;
  var xValues = document.getElementById("xValues").value.trim().split("\n");
  var yValues = document.getElementById("yValues").value.trim().split("\n");
  
  console.log(createDataPoints(xAxisLabel, xValues, yAxisLabel, yValues));
}

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", onImportClick);
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label> x-axis label
        <input type="text" id="xAxisLabel" value="orders">
      </label>
    </div>
    <label>
      x-values<br/>
      <textarea id="xValues" rows="10">
1
2
3
      </textarea>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label> y-axis label
        <input type="text" id="yAxisLabel" value="cost">
      </label>
    </div>
    <label>
      y-values<br/>
      <textarea id="yValues" rows="10">
2
4
9
      </textarea>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="calculate">import</button>
```